# nested absolute_imports python

Tags: python, python-import

I am a bit confused on getting imports done properly. I have a project as follows

```
mainpackge/

    packageone/
    __init__.py
    file.py
    file2.py
    file3.py
    subpackageone/
        __init__.py
        submodule1.py
        submodule2.py

    packagetwo/
    __init__.py
    file.py
    file2.py
    file3.py
    subpackagetwo/
        __init__.py
        submodule1.py
        submodule2.py
```

Inside the `packageone/subpackage/__init__.py` there is an absolute import as follows

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from subpackageone.submodule1 import ClassSubmodule1
```

Where ClassSubmodule1 is a class that i wish to use inside

```
packagetwo/subpackagetwo/submodule1.py
```

What needs to go inside the `packageone/__init__.py` file (currently its empty) in order for me to be able to import that class inside `packagetwo/subpackagetwo/submodule1.py`. Also can someone show how i would import the class (give import code).

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Basically, the import here:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from subpackageone.submodule1 import ClassSubmodule1
```

needs to be moved up to `packageone/__init__.py`. After i did that i was able to import into packagetwo no problem.